# Not able to set UI Text from another script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object "Text" which is a UI Text. It has a script(Scores.cs) which basically increments a score variable(public) based on some equation.

Now I want to set text from another script "GameManager.cs" to it, saying "Game Over" again based on some scenarios.

I am unable to do so.

**Scores.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
    public class Scores : MonoBehaviour {

        public Transform player;
        public Text scoreText;

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0");
        }
    }
```

**GameManager.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    bool gameEnded = false;
    public Text scoreText; // Also referrenced this variable with Text Object in the inspector


    public void EndGame() {
        if(gameEnded == false) {
            scoreText.text = "Game over";
            gameEnded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I set scoreText via scoreText.text, it sets correctly to "Game over" after I saw this by debugging, **but it never updates to the UI of the game**.

When I debug scoreText.text inside EndGame(), I get the respected score. I am able to get the score but not able to set it.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling EndGame ?  is the UI text you dragged on the same scene ? if you load a scene even if it still has a UI of the same name its a new instance

Comment: Yes Sir, it is on the same scene and I indeed call Endgame(), as when I debug scoreText.text inside EndGame(), I get the respected score. I am able to get the score but not able to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this part of the code in your `Scores.cs`:

```
//Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0");
}
```

Read the comment generated by Unity. It says that the `Update` function is called every frame. Basically, you are setting it in the `EndGame` function to *"Game over"* then overwrite its value in the `Update` function in the next frame when you did `scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0");`. You have to remove that or add a boolean variable to control when you should be able to set it in the `Update` function or not.

Comment: Good catch, great help. I wish my school had 1% of social help like here it is on SO, I would had learned alot alot

Comment: Np. You can always ask question on SO when lost. Many Unity users here to help.